# Error when i run a program on visual studio

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When i run a program on visual studio, it gives me this error: `command 'python.execlnTerminal-icon' not found` (python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using the built-in "Run" button. Instead, open a new built-in terminal, activate your `venv` or `conda` environment and then execute your script via terminal.